# Sending Push Notification in iOS without using any third party services like Parse or Urban Airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to send push notification to my device without using any third party services like Urban Airship and Parse in iOS, as when I was doing it in Android GCM I dint use any other third party services like these instead I have made my own app which I was using to send post request to GCM server which actually contains the push notification and broadcast the message to all the devices which have the client app installed, so is there any thing like this in iOS?

Comment: You might be looking for http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/sample-apple-push-notification-php-script/

Answer (score 2):

APNS is little more complex than GCM. The iOS developer has to create an APNS certificate and you should get the private key file from him. The app should be signed by a prov. file which has this APNS certificate. When the app runs, the app should register for push notification which will give a push notification token. You will need this token along with the key file to send a push notification.

The detailed procedure can be found here.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

The link shows the procedure for php file. Sample php file is [here](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in iOS no, but you can write your own server, that will send your push notifications to Apple. Just a simple request with couple certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response can you guide me little bit about it as I am new to it, just need a head start. @Soberman

Comment: Never really wrote a server backend, 'cause I don't know PHP or Python that much. But what my co-worker did, was a simple PHP file, that was sending request to Apple, while including your Provision Profile that includes push notifications. Pretty much it.